# A client event prevents my commands from working

Tags: discord.py

So I tried making a on_message event which detects a keyword and responds to it, but the problem is that now it doesn't let the other commands work?

```
async def on_message(message):
    if 'gay' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('no u')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the `on_message` event.